# Laravel Excel 3.1 export large data

Tags: laravel, laravel-excel

I need to export over 100K records to Excel from database using Maatwebsite Laravel excel 3.1 plugin, the problem is that I get data as an array.

```
$data = $this->client->getData("sc/asistencia-social/informe",$request->all());

 return (new ExcelExport($data))->store('myFile.xlsx'); //using FromQuery
```

My ExcelExport Class :

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class ExcelExport implements FromQuery
{
 use Exportable, SerializesModels;
 private $data;

public function __construct($data)
{   
   $this->data = $data;     //Inject data 
}

public function query()
{   
   return $this->data;  
}
}
```

Actually, I get a "Call to a member function chunk() on array" error. 
 I even tried to convert it into a collection with no success. Is there any possible solution to this.

Answer (score 2):

You have created your export class as `FromQuery` export class. instead create a `FromArray` export class.

**Note the Implement interface and the function name**

```php
class ExcelExport implements FromArray // this was FromQuery before
{
    use Exportable, SerializesModels;

    private $data;

    public function __construct($data)
    {   
        $this->data = $data;     //Inject data 
    }

    public function array(): array // this was query() before
    {   
        return $this->data;  
    }
}
```

Comment: I testes it and getting a "Declaration of App\Exports\ExcelExport::array() must be compatible with Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromArray::array(): array"

Comment: I think it's because of missing return type of `array()` function, Updated the answer

Comment: It's still running, it's taking more than 4 minutes to export aprox 30k records, I read the FromQuery leverages chunks,some say only on import but no export. is that so?

Comment: No, you __CAN__ use FromQuery to export too, and its better than this approach too. But if you want to do that, you don't want to pass data through the constructor. you need to write database query in the `query()` function. If there are lot of data in the database I think thats the best solution.

Comment: ok, in my case, $data = $this->client->getData("sc/asistencia-social/informe",$request->all()); send a request to the API to query the database,  the system doesn't make use of  ORM only plain sql with parameters like a range of dates, is it still possible?

Comment: Not possible. If you wanna use `FromQuery` approach you have to provide a sql query to that `query()` function. Then they will take care of fetching data from the database (there's where they apply chunks). Otherwise you can't use `FromQuery` approach.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `shouldQueue` to export large data to an Excel file.

Answer (score -3):

It Worked

In Query remove ->get() or replace with  ->paginate(100)

with maatwebsite queue export.